# Sphinx PHP One-to-Many Search

Tags: php, sphinx, one-to-many, categories

I have the following mysql tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `video` (
`video_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`description` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`video_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `video_categories` (
`cat_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `video_category` (
`video_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`cat_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
KEY `video_id` (`video_id`),
KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `video_tags` (
`tag_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`video_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
KEY `video_id` (`video_id`),
KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I created a sphinx configuration file and i can search from PHP. The problem is when i want to search for related videos, a related video must be in the same category as the video i'm searching for. I can do this with MVA and and SetFilter('categories', array(3)) for example, however the total number of matches results is the global one (i need total to display pagination via ajax) not the one in the category.

Any ideas how i can search through videos (documents in sphinx) that are only in a specified category?

Thanks,
Adrian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define for the category ID an [integer attribute](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#attributes) in Sphinx:

```
sql_attr_uint = cat_id
```

And then just add `@cat_id=12345` to your query.

Comment: For that you can use multi-value attributes: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#mva

Comment: I used MVA with SetFilter. What i need is the total number of related videos in the specified category. MVA actually does a global search (in all categories) and then i can use SetFilter to filter my results.